# Lyx doesn't generate pdf when using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, errors, packages, lyx, luatex

If I don't use hyperref package everything's fine, but if I use it, after a while a message appears with something like "Command dvilualatex "filename.tex" has not yet completed. Do you want to stop it?" and I don't get my pdf. I use Lualatex.
These are the packages that I use:

```
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: If you're using a recent version of LyX, it has native support for hyperref. Check `Document -> Settings... -> PDF Properties`.

Comment: Do you really use `dvilualatex`, that is lualatex with dvi output? Imho this doesn't make much sense as there is no sensible driver to handle the dvi.

Comment: I'm on version 2.0.6 and I use article as class. Ulrike, to be honest I have no idea of what I'm using, I just press View PDF (LuaTeX)... It doesn't work even if I check the option in PDF properties.

Comment: If I try to export it as a pdf with lualatex, the message is "The command lualatex "filename.tex"..." No mention of dvi but still no pdf either.

Comment: The things not working are the bookmarks, once they're disabled, the pdf is generated and the links works fine. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to conflict of `mhchem` and `hyperref` packages. The `hyperref` package seems not be able to handle titles (section, subsection...) that contain the `\ce{}` command.

A temporary solution is:

```
\section[title H$_2$O]{title \ce{H2O}}
```

This keeps the H2O in the title in the font of `\section` (bold, bigger), while  `hyperref` still functions (for putting the tile in TOC for example).